# Python session.put return 415: Unsupported Media Type

Tags: python, put

I do not know why I receive the respone:
"415: Unsupported Media Type"

I try to put new values.
When I get some values it works fine.

code snippet:

```
headers = {}
headers["charset"] = "utf-8"
headers["Accept-Language"] = "pl-PL"
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

headers["Accept"] = "application/vnd.allegro.public.v1+json"
headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer {}".format(access_token)

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)
    DEFAULT_API_URL = "https://api.allegro.pl"
    payload = {"maxAmount": {"amount": "230.00", "currency": "PLN"}}

    response = session.put(
        url=DEFAULT_API_URL + "/bidding/offers/1498090700/bid",
        json=json.dumps(payload),
    )

    print(f"{response.status_code}: {response.reason}")
    print(response.json())
```

Response:
"415: Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: Presumably the API doesn't accept `application/json` (or the non-standard `charset` header you're trying to use). Look at the docs for the API.

Answer (score 0):

According [to the API documentation](https://developer.allegro.pl/documentation#operation/placeBid), the content type of the request also needs to be `application/vnd.allegro.public.v1+json`. Try e.g.

```
ALLEGRO_JSON = "application/vnd.allegro.public.v1+json"
DEFAULT_API_URL = "https://api.allegro.pl"
headers = {
    "Accept-Language": "pl-PL",
    "Content-Type": ALLEGRO_JSON,
    "Accept": ALLEGRO_JSON,
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    payload = {"maxAmount": {"amount": "230.00", "currency": "PLN"}}

    response = session.put(
        url=DEFAULT_API_URL + "/bidding/offers/1498090700/bid",
        json=payload,
        headers=headers,
    )

    print(f"{response.status_code}: {response.reason}")
    print(response.json())
```

Comment: You are right. I need also change the json=json.dumps(payload) to this:
json=payload

and now it works fine.
Thank you!

Comment: Ah, yeah, in that case `body=json.dumps(payload)` would work too, but the end result is the same. Glad I could help!